# Slick Carousel unable to call Methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have several instances of the [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) gallery set up and working properly. However, I cannot successfully call the Methods as described in the documentation. (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Whenever I try to target an existing instance of the carousel, I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeSlide' of undefined." I'm trying to automatically goto the next slide after the gallery is initiated.

I've put together this jsfiddle to replicate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/d32x7nqp/

```
var gallery = $('.slick-container');
    gallery.slick({
        speed:100,
        dots:true,
        onInit: function(){
            gallery.slickNext();
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeSlide' of undefined
```

Targeting *this, $(this), $('.slick-container')*, and *gallery* all produce the same exception. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!!

### EDIT

Thanks to Sunand for the fix! For those dealing with the same issue, simply move your method out of the onInit callback. Apparently the slick instance is not fully initialized when onInit is called. Here's the correct code:

```
var gallery = $('.slick-container');
    gallery.slick({
        speed:100,
        dots:true,
    });

gallery.slickNext();
```

Comment: can you tell how are you calling the methods?

Comment: Sunand, please see the jsfiddle that I included in my post.

Comment: the error is because that component is not completely initialised when onInit is called. If just want to call next after initialisation call it after you call the slick plugin.

Answer (score 6):

I'm noticing after upgrading my slick.js a lot of the methods like slickPrev() etc are gone. Looks like the way to call them now seems to be

```
$('selector').slick('slickPrev');
```